# Keyboard key label not changing color on press

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have this keyboard in one of the layouts of my app

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@color/lightBlue"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/list_item_selector"
        android:keyTextColor="@color/drawer_text_color_selector"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
```

it all works ok except the color selection of the text inside the keys. When i press it i want it to change colors.
In case of the background it changes correctly , but the text stays the same color

this is the xml i use for the text color

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/bodyTextSelectedColor"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/bodyTextSelectedColor"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/bodyTextSelectedColor"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/bodyTextSelectedColor"/>
    <item android:color="@color/bodyTextColor"/>
</selector>
```

where `bodyTextSelectedColor` is white and `bodyTextColor` is black
should i change something in my KeyboardView or my selector?

Answer (score 2):

KeyBoardView does not support selectors for the textColor, at least not officially.

In the [documentation for KeyboardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView), android:keyBackground mentions selectors while the entry for keyTextcolor simply states:

> Color to use for the label in a key.
>
> May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or
>   "#aarrggbb".

Further evidence is that your syntax seems correct and applying it to the keyBackground changes the background as expected.